# Can windows managed service be a wcf client?

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

On 1st server, there is wcf service hosted in windows managed service. On the 2nd server, there is another wcf service, hosted in their own windows managed service. I try to connect to 1st service from the inside of the 2nd service, but I become a exception "The socket connection was aborted". With same configuration and same code I successfully connect from console application and winform application, but not from this windows managed service.

Comment: Sorry - crystal ball is out of batteries ..... you'll need to provide **a lot more** relevant info for us to be able to answer...... configs, service contract, **exact** error message.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Configure your WCF services on both servers to perform diagnostic logging. Follow the instructions in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx to achieve that.
2. Make sure the account your service on server 2 is running under is capable of connecting to server 1. This is a typical difference between the client test you did (and worked) and a service running on that system. For a test, make the service on server 2 run under your personal login credentials.

Comment: i try logon service as an admin and service is working well, thx